Problem make publisher in action github for ElectronJs application?
I want to publish a version of my application on the Github release page with a Github action. I tried using the Electron Builder Action but it made an error.
I used this YML, but it didn't create an output file and I have only the source file on that page.
name: Release
on: push

jobs:

  release:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}

    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: [macos-latest, ubuntu-latest, windows-latest]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3       
      - uses: actions/setup-node@master
        with:
          node-version: 18
      - name: install dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: publish
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        run: npm run publish
      - name: Upload artifacts
        uses: LabhanshAgrawal/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          path: |
            out/make/**/*.zip
            out/make/**/*.exe
            out/make/**/*.deb
            out/make/**/*.rpm


If you don’t mind creating the releases manually, you could modify your YML to run the action when you publish the release.
on:
  release:
    types: [published]

Then, an example workflow would be:

Go to your repository’s Releases page
Click ‘Draft a new release’
Create a tag for the release. I use vX.X.X naming convention.
Give the release a title and description
Click ‘Publish release’

This will trigger your Github action to run, and when completed, will publish all the output files under that release.
